# Store images in a MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, database

How can I store images in a MongoDB database rather than just text? Can I create an array of images in a MongoDB database? Will it be possible to do the same for videos?

Comment: The short answer is: Yes, you can store (small) images if you encode them correctly with `base64`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442356/ I also found http://menge.io/2015/03/24/storing-small-images-in-mongodb/ a very good starting point.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Please see the [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) docs for details on storing such binary data.

Support for your specific language should be linked to at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: GridFS is for documents > 16MB.  Not all binary data is this large.  Other than being able to surpass that limit, is there any other benefits to using GridFS instead of just the BinData type?

Comment: Videos will tend to be > 16MB so this answer is probably reasonable. Should perhaps mention this though.

Comment: any other solution, rather then using GridFS?

Comment: @AbhishekMani the other solution is not to store them in MongoDB at all. Now, in 2018, it's infinitely easier to write this data to something like Amazon's S3 or Azure BLOB storage.

Comment: I think what the MongoDB says

Comment: @GatesVP can you reply to Brandon question "GridFS is for documents > 16MB. Not all binary data is this large. Other than being able to surpass that limit, is there any other benefits to using GridFS instead of just the BinData type?" Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Nux, this question is from 2011, that's over 8 years ago. In 2019, the answer to Brandon's question is irrelevant. Don't use MongoDB for storing binary data like this, we have _way_ better solutions for storing (_and streaming_) data efficiently.

Comment: @GatesVP, I use Azure Blob Storage  + Azure CDN to store and distribute images on my website https://www.indievisible.net

Comment: @BrandonFitzpatrick very old comment I know, but the docs say that GridFS is _suggested_ for files over 16MB. There's no minimum file size requirement.

Answer (score 79):

> "You should always use GridFS for storing files larger than 16MB" - [When should I use GridFS?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#when-to-use-gridfs)

MongoDB [BSON documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size) are capped at 16 MB. So if the total size of your array of files is less than that, you may store them directly in your document using the [BinData](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) data type.

Videos, images, PDFs, spreadsheets, etc. - it doesn't matter, they are all treated the same. It's up to your application to return an appropriate content type header to display them.

Check out the [GridFS documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) for more details.

Answer (score 28):

You can try this one:

```
String newFileName = "my-image";
File imageFile = new File("/users/victor/images/image.png");
GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(db, "photo");
GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gfsPhoto.createFile(imageFile);
gfsFile.setFilename(newFileName);
gfsFile.save();
```

Answer (score 14):

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/183689081/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb

There is a Mongoose plugin available on NPM called mongoose-file. It lets you add a file field to a Mongoose Schema for file upload. I have never used it but it might prove useful. 
If the images are very small you could Base64 encode them and save the string to the database.

[Storing some small (under 1MB) files with MongoDB in NodeJS WITHOUT GridFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442356/storing-some-small-under-1mb-files-with-mongodb-in-nodejs-without-gridfs)

Answer (score 14):

install below libraries

```
var express = require(‘express’);
var fs = require(‘fs’);
var mongoose = require(‘mongoose’);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var multer = require('multer');
```

connect ur mongo db :

```
mongoose.connect(‘url_here’);
```

Define database Schema

```
var Item = new ItemSchema({ 
    img: { 
       data: Buffer, 
       contentType: String 
    }
 }
);
var Item = mongoose.model('Clothes',ItemSchema);
```

using the middleware Multer to upload the photo on the server side.

```
app.use(multer({ dest: ‘./uploads/’,
  rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename;
  },
}));
```

post req to our db

```
app.post(‘/api/photo’,function(req,res){
  var newItem = new Item();
  newItem.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.userPhoto.path)
  newItem.img.contentType = ‘image/png’;
  newItem.save();
});
```

Comment: Sir what if I want to add array of Images

Comment: @NikhilPatil, you can use something like this: `var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }); app.post('/api/photos/', upload.array('photos', 12), function(req, res) {...})`
 [see the doc on Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage)

Comment: How can I display image from mongo

Answer (score 10):

You can use the bin data type if you are using any scripting language to store files/images in MongoDB. Bin data is developed to store small size of files.

Refer to your scripting language driver. For PHP, click [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-driver-legacy/class.mongobindata.html).

Answer (score 9):

**Can you store files in MongoDB?**

Yes.

**Should you store files in MongoDB?**

No.

---

MongoDB is **NOT** a good place for storing files. If you want to store files, you should use storages like Amazon S3 or Google Could Storage.

The good practice is to store the files in a storage and then to just save the URI of the uploaded image in the MongoDB.

Comment: While I agree, Cloud Storage isn't always an option. Thus why you can use [GridFS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var upload = multer({dest: "./uploads"});
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
Grid.mongo = mongo;

router.post('/:id', upload.array('photos', 200), function(req, res, next){
gfs = Grid(db);
var ss = req.files;
   for(var j=0; j<ss.length; j++){
     var originalName = ss[j].originalname;
     var filename = ss[j].filename;
     var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
         filename: originalName
     });
    fs.createReadStream("./uploads/" + filename).pipe(writestream);
   }
});
```

In your view:

```
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photos">
```

With this code you can add single as well as multiple images in MongoDB.