# How to store wavefront .obj models in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, 3d, three.js, webgl

I am trying to store 3d models in the .obj format into a database. I am using a mongodb database. How do approach this problem? do I convert it to binary or something?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not store entire model in the database (mongodb or any other).
You just store the link to the .obj file on your server.
Similar thing as with the images, you just store url to them, not the entire object.

```
ID    Name     Url
0     dragon   /models/dragon.obj
1     sponza   /models/sponza_scene.obj
2     rabbit   /models/rabbit.obj
...
```

If you for some reason need to store data directly into the database, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongo-database).

Comment: Thanks..I'll try that out. Was going through GridFS and  BinData option of mongodb