# How to save image to mongodb having image url?

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I have following question: I need to save image to mongodb during web scraping. I have an image link. I tried this:

```
images_binaries = [] # this will store all images data before saving it to mongodb
# save as file on hard disc
urllib.urlretrieve(url, self.album_path + '/' + photo_file_name)
images_binaries.append(open(self.album_path + '/' + photo_file, 'r').read())
....
# after that I append this array of images raw data to Item
post = WaralbumPost()
post['images_binary'] = images_binaries
....
```

The code of Waralbum item:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class WaralbumPost(Item):
    images_binary = Field()
```

But this cause error when it saves to mongo: `bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: '\xff\.....`

What is better way to do this? Does converting of raw image data will solve this problem? Maybe, scrapy has a pretty way for saving images?
Thank for your answers

SOLUTION:
I deleted this lines:
    images_binaries.append(open(self.album_path + '/' + photo_file, 'r').read())
    post['images_binary'] = images_binaries
In my WaralbumPost I also save image url. Than, in pipelines.py I get this url and save image in mongo. the code of pipelines.py:

```
class WarAlbum(object):
def __init__(self):
    connection = pymongo.Connection(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
    db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
    self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]
    self.grid_fs = gridfs.GridFS(getattr(connection, settings['MONGODB_DB']))

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    links = item['img_links']
    ids = []
    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        mime_type = mimetypes.guess_type(link)[0]
        request = requests.get(link, stream=True)
        _id = self.grid_fs.put(request.raw, contentType=mime_type, filename=item['local_images'][i])
        ids.append(_id)
    item['data_chunk_id'] = ids
    self.collection.insert(dict(item))
    log.msg("Item wrote to MongoDB database %s/%s" %
            (settings['MONGODB_DB'], settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']),
            level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
    return item
```

Hope, this will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use GridFS.  [Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongo-database)

```
String newFileName = "my-image";
File imageFile = new File("/users/victor/images/image.png");
GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(db, "photo");
GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gfsPhoto.createFile(imageFile);
gfsFile.setFilename(newFileName);
gfsFile.save();
```

Comment: I guess, this is java code. But I solved my problem. See update to question

Comment: oops!  Sorry to post Java to a Python question :)