# How to identify image and text from mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mahout, nosql

I want store mixed data of text and image together in mongodb database. My later part of the work would be to identify text and image separately from the mixed set of data. How can I do the above mentioned steps ? Is it suitable with mongodb or I should try like hadoop or mahout ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered on StackOverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4800186/3993224

In addition, MongoDB provides information regarding storage of large files (such as images) here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

I would assume that the way you would store your image is as a key/value pair of a document or as an embedded document within a document. Ideally you would want to store the text associated with the image in another key/value pair within the same document, so that you have the image and the text together.

Answer (score 0):

Your links will be very much helpful for data storage.

My plan is to store data but no flag that helps later to identify text or image separately.I need to identify text and image separately only by reading the binary content not by reading any information embedded with data.

N.B. both the text and image will be in binary format.