# Uploading saving and showing images with node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image

I can already have a user upload their own image by url and then showing the image back to the user (storing the url in the db) but i want to have a user upload their own image and have it stored in the database and being able to show it back to the user (example a profile image or a blog post with an image). I can't seem to find a tutorial on how to do it and i was wondering if someone could walk me through the entire process.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongo-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store images in a mongo database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongo-database)