# Storing images in MongoDb Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to store images in my existing collection.
For example, one of my document looks like

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5dc5a4851c9d440000cb2d5b"},"Name":"Johnny's Tavern","Monday":"11:30am-10pm","Tuesday":"11:30am-10pm","Wednesday":"11:30am-10pm","Thursday":"11:30am-10pm","Friday":"11:30am-10pm","Saturday":"11:30am-10pm","Sunday":"11:30am-10pm"}
```

So I'm trying to add a field "pic" to store an image like https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/11/fc/6d/bb/restaurant-frontage.jpg either using the url link or from file explorer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store images in a MongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongodb-database)