# Adding photos to users collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, image

I am new to using mongodb, I have a collection of users, I want every user to upload some of their photos. So, I am thinking of creating property called images for every user document. this would be an array of images. However, I don't know if it's applicable or not, or how to do so. Any ideas? I am using node.js

Comment: For some performance, latency and verbose implementation reasons you could/should avoid storing images in db altogether. Instead use file system/storage service to store the photos to a location using neat utility like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) and maintain a unique identifer reference of that location in the db for a user's photo retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

There multiple libraries that are created to help store images in a MongoDB database. You can see some at this question: [Store images in a MongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongodb-database)

Also, for good design, you should consider having the images property containing IDs that correspond to the image, instead of the actual images themselves; it would be named `imageIds`.