# How to store an image in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

How can I store an image into MongoDB using the below scenario.

- Below is my product schema, I want to add another field image into it and manually post the image along with the other fields using **Product.create** or **Product.insertMany** method (example below).
- Inserting image manually means I have grabbed some product images from Google but I am unable to figure out how to store them in MongoDB and use them in my front end.
- My goal is just to display all the products using the **frontend React app** along with the image and its details.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  category: String,
  price: Number,
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

```
// Product.insertMany(
//   [
//     { name: 'Shoe one', category: 'Shoes', price: 3599 },
//     { name: 'Shirt one', category: 'Upperwear', price: 380 },
//   ],
//   (err) => {
//     if (err) console.log('error');
//   }
// );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store images in a MongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongodb-database)

Answer (score 1):

Store your image as an array by using type Buffer as follows

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    category: String,
    price: Number,
    img:
    {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }

});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

Comment: Okay, but then how will i manually post an image to db using post.create ?
Means how what value should i put for the img.data key -- 
`{ name: 'Shirt one', category: 'Upperwear', price: 380, img: {data : ?????} }`

Comment: @SatyamGupta, check this URL out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485420/how-do-you-put-an-image-file-in-a-json-object

Basically you need to convert your image to Base64 encoding and then convert it back later at server end. Read the URL above.